# Add 'x' number of hours to date

Tags: php, date, datetime, dateadd, hour

I currently have php returning the current date/time like so:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

What I'd like to do is have a new variable `$new_time` equal `$now + $hours`, where `$hours` is a number of hours ranging from 24 to 800.

Any suggestions?

Comment: strtotime() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: I doubt if it is what you want. I want you to notice that "m" in "H:m:s" represents month on digit. I believe you wanted to write "H:i:s". Please crosscheck

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You may use something like the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to add something to the current timestamp. `$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours'))`.

If you need variables in the function, you must use double quotes then like `strtotime("+{$hours} hours")`, however better you use `strtotime(sprintf("+%d hours", $hours))` then.

Comment: That works, but if i replace the '5' with a variable, it doesnt work properly. `strtotime('+$hours hours')`

Comment: Don't you mean $new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours')? m is month, i is minutes...

Comment: For me, the use of `{$hours}`  `strtotime("+{$hours} hours")` did not work. I replaced `{$hours}` with `'.$hours.'`. So instead of an {} I used ``. Hope this helps someone in need

Answer (score 54):

An other solution (object-oriented) is to use DateTime::add

Example:

```php
<?php

$now = new DateTime(); //now
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-09-11 01:01:55

$hours = 36; // hours amount (integer) you want to add
$modified = (clone $now)->add(new DateInterval("PT{$hours}H")); // use clone to avoid modification of $now object
echo "\n". $modified->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-09-12 13:01:55
```

[Run script](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8d43aa22a4177850970e290d8a7ab5cf394ef7d)

---

- [DateTime::add PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)
- [DateInterval::construct PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

Comment: Small tyop here, $date->format should probably be $now->format

Comment: While I appreciate the link to PHP Documentation, it would be nice to describe what the parameters in your example do.  You linked to the `DateTime::add` function, which takes the parameter of `DateInterval` whose doc then says to refer to the formats supported by the `DateTime` constructor which then points to "Date and Time Formats" which then links to "Time Formats", "Date Formats", "Compound Formats" and "Relative Formats".  None of these seem to mention `P`, though I could very well have missed it in all those pages.  I get that `T` means time, `H` hours, but `P`?....

Comment: @s.co.tt https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php 
The format starts with the letter P, for period. Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T.

Comment: Thanks!  I did figure it out, and please note I was irritated with the PHP docs, not the poster.  But I'm glad your answer is here for posterity!

Answer (score 26):

You can use  [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to achieve this:

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', $now)); // $now + 3 hours
```

Comment: @RichardDesLonde Probably because everyone copied the OP's code example. :-)

Comment: This did not work for me, Rodrigo Prazim's answer did.

Comment: A non well formed numeric value encountered - doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn’t it be: `$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($now.' + 3 hours'));`

Answer (score 17):

**Correct**

You can use strtotime() to achieve this:

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', strtotime($now))); // $now + 3 hours
```

Comment: Best answer because i can change now to any date i want

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the unix style time to calculate:

```
$newtime = time() + ($hours * 60 * 60); // hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $newtime) ."\n";
```

Comment: bad idea, issues with leap years, leap seconds, daylight savings time etc.

Comment: @Dagon no, it will calculate properly.

Comment: Leap years are taken care of using this method, daylight saving can be set while using date again

Answer (score 7):

I use this , its working cool.

```
//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

//set an date and time to work with
$start = '2014-06-01 14:00:00';

//display the converted time
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+1 hour +20 minutes',strtotime($start)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Um... your minutes should be corrected... 'i' is for minutes. Not months. :) (I had the same problem for something too.

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 hours', $now)); // $now + 3 hours
```

Answer (score 6):

for add 2 hours to "now"

```
$date = new DateTime('now +2 hours');
```

or

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+2 hours', $now)); // as above in example
```

or

```
$now = new DateTime();

$now->add(new DateInterval('PT2H')); // as above in example
```

Answer (score 3):

`$to =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //"2022-01-09 12:55:46"`

`$from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$to -3 hours")); // 2022-01-09 09:55:46`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can try lib [Ouzo goodies](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/clock.html), and do this in fluent way:

```
echo Clock::now()->plusHours($hours)->format("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

API's allow multiple operations.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date_to_be-added="2018-04-11 10:04:46";
$added_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+24 hours', strtotime($date_to_be)));
```

A combination of [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

For a given DateTime, you can add days, hours, minutes, etc. Here's some examples:

```
$now = new \DateTime();

$now->add(new DateInterval('PT24H')); // adds 24 hours

$now->add(new DateInterval('P2D')); // adds 2 days
```

PHP: DateTime::add - Manual https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php

Answer (score -3):

```
   $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours $now"));
```