# I have time like this 12:00:00 AM how to add + two hours with the time

Tags: php

I have time like this 10:00:00 AM how to add + two hours with the time.

I have tried this:

```
$today = "10:00:00 am"; 
$starttime = "02:00:00"; 
$endtime = date("g:i:s a", $starttime+$today);
echo $endtime;
```

Answer (score 3):

I vanilla PHP, object style using [`DataTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('10:00:00 AM');
$date->modify('+2 hours');
echo $date->format("g:i:s a");
```

Output:

```
12:00:00 pm
```

---

Or you can try lib [Ouzo goodies](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/clock.html), and do this in fluent way:

```
echo Clock::at('10:00:00 AM')->plusHours(2)->format("g:i:s a");
```

Output:

```
12:00:00 pm
```

Comment: i got answer Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it works

```
 $endtime = date("g:i:s a", strtotime('+2 hours', $starttime + $today));
```

Comment: its not working send another code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$today = "10:00:00 am"; 
$endtime = date("g:i:s a", strtotime("+2 hours",strtotime($today)));
echo $endtime;
?>
```

[Add 'x' amount of hours to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-amount-of-hours-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$today = "10:00:00 am"; 
$starttime = "02:00:00"; 
$endtime = date("g:i:s a", strtotime("+2 hours", $starttime + $today));
echo $endtime;
```

Answer (score 0):

More object oriented approach is using `DateTime` and `DateInterval`.

```
$start_date = new DateTime($result->start_date);
$start_date->add(new DateInterval('P' . (int)$probation_length . 'M'));
```

Adjust to fit your needs.