# Add number of hours to date through "variable" in php not statically

Tags: php, date, time

I have stored the date and time in database like this `2015-06-31 14:00` And i want to add some `hours` to the `date` field through variable how can i add

```
<?php
//set an date and time to work with
$start = '2015-06-31 14:00';
$hours='05:00';

//display the converted time
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime("+{$hours} hours",strtotime($start)));
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 'x' amount of hours to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-amount-of-hours-to-date)

Comment: But this one not working for me can you explain whats wrong with this code

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: as I add 5.00 hrs then it  will show 2015-06-31 19:00 or when i add 12:00 hrs it will show 2015-07-01 02:00

Comment: 2015-06-31 its a wrong date, please check calendar, it should be 2015-06-30

Comment: ok sorry but this one for example as you take 2015-10-31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$start = '2015-10-31 14:00';
$hours = '05:00';

$date = new DateTime($start);
$date->modify(sprintf("+%d hours", $hours));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i");
?>
```

**Output:**

```
2015-10-31 19:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
//set an date and time to work with
$start = '2015-06-30 14:00';
$hours= 5;

//display the converted time
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime("+{$hours} hours",strtotime($start)));
```

The output is `2015-06-30 19:00`

Comment: perfect, you fixed the date!