# Issue with strtotime() and setting timezone

Tags: php

I get how to use `strtotime`, but I first need to set a timezone, which is causing an issue:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$idate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$fdate=strtotime($idate,"+2 hours");
```

`$idate` comes out fine, in the correct timezone, in this format: `2016-07-25 15:56:24`

How can I add 2 hours onto this and return a variable in the same format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 'x' amount of hours to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-amount-of-hours-to-date)

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-amount-of-hours-to-date - it has several good answers. My favorite one is the OO answer.

Comment: `$fdate = $date->modify('+2 hours');`

Comment: I suggest you take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php. Also, `strtotime` converts a human-readable string into a number representing the datetime, and it is completely independent of the class `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fdate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($idate."+2 hours"));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks. I'll accept when I can in a few minutes.

Comment: glad i could be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

Using your `$date`, you can do:

```
$date = $date->add(new DateInterval('PT2H'));
```

and then format it as you like.