# Failed to parse string in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have made an online booking application for a small company. Where clients can book their own appointment.

Some people helped me with testing and I found a bug the next bug in my PHP error log:

Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (20/01/2022, 09:00:00) at position 0 (2)

This is my code:

```
$email = $_GET["email"];
$start_tijd = new DateTime(date($_GET["date"]));
$end_tijd =  new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i" , (strtotime($_GET["date"]) + 3600)));
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $full_name = $voornaam." ".$achternaam;
    $title = "Consult ".$full_name;
}
else{
    $title = $_GET["title"];
    $full_name = substr($title, 8);
    $clientID = last_client_id();
}
$query = "
INSERT INTO events 
(title, start_event, end_event, clientID, locatie) 
VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event, :clientID, :type)
";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(
array(
':title'  => $title,
':start_event' => $start_tijd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
':end_event' => $end_tijd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
':clientID' => $clientID,
':type' => $_GET["type"]
)
);
send_appointment_email($email, $full_name, $start_tijd->format('d-m-Y H:i:s'), $end_tijd->format('H:i:s'), $clientID);
```

About 25 people have booked an appointment and 2 people got the bug.

Comment: I doubt it can parse 20/01/2022 because  its d/m/y rather than  the default  m/d/y or the universal y/m/d. Use DateTime::createFromFormat if you  want to support other date formats  in the input  data

Comment: Also, please remember to [properly indent](/markdown) you code =)

Comment: You should not be using `strtotime` or `date`. Just use `DateTime`

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your feedback I am gonna change the date format. But I don't get why the bug appears not always.

Comment: Can you tell what date this is? `01/02/2022`? Without knowing the format PHP can't guess accurately

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for your feedback, but how do I add an hour to datetime? I used that because I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-number-of-hours-to-date/17942233

Comment: In the post you linked the second answer shows how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/23103855/1839439 You can also read from PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: @Dharman 01/02/2022 is a date a client picked on a jquery calendar. But in my country we use the notation d/m/y

Comment: I don't know how your UI looks like. Your job is to ensure that users provide the date in the correct format every time. Usually we use ISO 8601 format for this. If you think they will always give you date in format `d/m/y` you might be wrong.

Comment: @Dharman I have a textbox where the user can see the selected date. The date from the textbox is from the datepicker and the user is not able to typ in the textbox. And I am going to look at the manual and the second answer.